# ¿Cómo asignar un alias a los Joins en laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo varios Joins en una consulta y quisiera darle un alias para diferenciarlos, y así poder utilizar el id de usuarios, ya que al tratar de mostrarlos en la vista me da un error y supongo que laravel no sabe a cual id me estoy refieriendo porque tengo otros campos llamos id en las otras tablas.

Gracias, mi código es el siguiente:

```
public function myFunction($data)
{

    $data = DB::table('users')
        ->join('cities', 'users.city_id', "=", 'cities.id')
        ->join('provinces', 'cities.province_id', "=", 'provinces.id')
        ->where('code', $users)
        ->get();


    return view('users', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: lo haces como lo harías con una consulta normal , algo así creo DB::table('users  as u')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de las comillas, donde declaras la tablas con la que se va a hacer el `join` le puedes pasar el alias; tu consulta debería quedar de este modo

```
$data = DB::table('users')
    ->join('cities as c', 'users.city_id', "=", 'c.id')
    ->join('provinces as p', 'c.province_id', "=", 'p.id')
    ->where('code', $users)
    ->get();


return view('users', compact('data'));
```

> Donde como puedes notar a cada tabla invocada en los `joins` le he
>   asignado un alias y posteriormente cuando comparo las columnas de
>   dichas tablas, ya no escribo el nombre completo sino el alias que le
>   asigne a cada una

*ACTUALIZACIÓN*

Si deseas que todas tus tablas tengan un alias, tu código debería quedar así

```
$data = DB::table('users as u')
    ->join('cities as c', 'u.city_id', "=", 'c.id')
    ->join('provinces as p', 'c.province_id', "=", 'p.id')
    ->where('code', $users)
    ->get();


return view('users', compact('data'));
```

> Como puedes observar, tanto el método `table()` el método `join()`
>   aceptan los nombres de las tablas en forma de cadena de texto; en ese
>   mismo espacio puedes aprovechar y colocar el alias, con la estructura
>   regular de SQL `tableName as alias`

Comment: Gracias, ya lo intento.